# Recoil from a shotgun

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws

First of all I'd like to point out that I'm a complete layman when it comes to physics and I apologise if this isn't the correct forum for this.

If I were to sit on an office chair on a laminated floor and fired a shotgun out in front of me roughly how far backwards would I [recoil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recoil), imagine I weight 170lbs, I'll let you choose both the office chair and shotgun being used (I haven't got a shotgun to use as an example, this is purely hypothetical).

Also if I was to fire the shotgun in the same situation as above but facing a wall would I be projected further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this article](http://hunting.about.com/od/shotgun/l/aastshotgunfaqa.htm) (the choice of article has no significance other than it came up first in my Google search):

> Remington's 12-gauge 2 3/4-inch Premier Magnum turkey load has 1 1/2 ounces of shot and a 1260 fps muzzle velocity

Converting these figures to metric, $m_{\text{shot}} = 0.0425$ kg and $v_{\text{shot}} = 384$ m/sec, so the momentum of the shot is:

$$ p = m_{\text{shot}}v_{\text{shot}} = 16.3 \space \text{kg.m/s} $$

To conserve momentum your momentum would also change by the same amount, so:

$$ m_{\text{Luke}}v_{\text{Luke}} = m_{\text{shot}}v_{\text{shot}} = 16.3 $$

and if we divide $16.3$ by your mass of about $77$ kg we find your velocity to be:

$$ v_{\text{Luke}} = \frac{16.3}{77} = 0.21 \space \text{m/s} $$

Your question asked how far the chair would move, but there is no way to calculate this because it depends on the frictional losses as the chair rolls and I have no way to know this. The best I can do is give you the initial velocity of the chair ($0.21$ m/s). You'd have to try experimentally measuring the chair+you roll distance as a function of initial velocity to determine the distance.

Comment: yeah, but how far would he move? you need some office chair parameters too

Comment: @Aksakal: it's impossible to predict how far the chair would move. That will depend on the friction in the wheels and the surface that it's rolling on. Since I rather doubt the manufacturers provide this information you would have to determine the frictional loses in the chair by experiment.

Comment: Don't forget the momentum of the gases that leave the barrel along with the shot (but at higher speeds)...

Comment: Shouldn't this question be closed now?

Comment: @User58220: true, though I have no way of knowing what fraction of the momentum is carried by the gases. In any case, I think this is one of those approximate calculations in which understanding the method is more important than the final result.

Comment: @JohnRennie Thanks for the reply, would the initial velocity be higher if I was facing a wall when I fired the shot?

Comment: @Luke: once the shot has left the gun it has no further effect on you, so facing a wall would make no difference (unless the shot ricochets off the wall and hits you!).